# Local state in container component

Tags: reactjs

For the simplicity I am referring react's example shopping cart app found at https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart

In Container component at CartContiner, it has Cart component.

Scenario: The cart has a dropdown control (or any control) which updates local state (not redux) using this.setState() method.

Question: Where should this setState reside? should it go to container or should remain in cart.js file.

Will be great if you can provide code snippet.

CartContainer.js :

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { checkout } from '../actions'
import { getTotal, getCartProducts } from '../reducers'
import Cart from '../components/Cart'

const CartContainer = ({ products, total, checkout }) => (
  <Cart
    products={products}
    total={total}
    onCheckoutClicked={() => checkout(products)} />
)

CartContainer.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    price: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    quantity: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  })).isRequired,
  total: PropTypes.string,
  checkout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: getCartProducts(state),
  total: getTotal(state)
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { checkout }
)(CartContainer)
```

cart.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Product from './Product'

const Cart  = ({ products, total, onCheckoutClicked }) => {
  const hasProducts = products.length > 0
  const nodes = hasProducts ? (
    products.map(product =>
      <Product
        title={product.title}
        price={product.price}
        quantity={product.quantity}
        key={product.id}
      />
    )
  ) : (
    <em>Please add some products to cart.</em>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Your Cart</h3>
      <div>{nodes}</div>
      <p>Total: &#36;{total}</p>
      <button onClick={onCheckoutClicked}
        disabled={hasProducts ? '' : 'disabled'}>
        Checkout
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

Cart.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.array,
  total: PropTypes.string,
  onCheckoutClicked: PropTypes.func
}

export default Cart
```

Comment: setState *has* to be written in the same component where the state is defined, otherwise `this` will be somebody else's state. you can wrap `this.setState` in another function though and pass it down to child components who in turn call it, but there's not right or wrong answer for that

Comment: Off topic. You shouldn't have CartContainer at all, instead: export default connect(mapStateToProps, { checkout })(Cart); is the CartContainer itself.

Comment: @croraf, I quite didn't understand it, if we use your code then how the enter cartContainer.js will look like? btw: this is not mine, it is from React guys.

Comment: Yes. I saw now it is redux official, so maybe my comment is not needed :D.
Sorry "enter cartContainer.js" will look like?

Comment: Done sir @croraf

Comment: Right now, the only option is to store state in redux, no local state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made button control to change internal state. What I did:

1. Convert to class component (React.Component) - moved entire body to render(){...}, and using this.props.propertyname
2. Use constructor and toggleState method.
3. in button onClick assign toggleState()

Sorry about the code formatting and possible bugs. Ask if unclear.

Cart.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Product from './Product'

class Cart  extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {on: false};
     this.toggleState = this.toggleState.bind(this);
  }

  toggleState() {
     this.setState({on: !this.state.on});
     // you can use this.props even here
     // this.props.onCheckoutClicked();
  }

  render () {

    const hasProducts = this.props.products.length > 0
    const nodes = hasProducts ? (
    products.map(product =>
      <Product
        title={product.title}
        price={product.price}
        quantity={product.quantity}
        key={product.id}
      />
    )
    ) : (
     <em>Please add some products to cart.</em>
    )
    return (
    <div>
      <h3>Your Cart</h3>
      <div>{nodes}</div>
      <p>Total: &#36;{this.props.total}</p>
      <button onClick={this.toggleState} //{this.props.onCheckoutClicked}
        disabled={hasProducts ? '' : 'disabled'}>
        Checkout
      </button>
    </div>
  )
 }
}

Cart.propTypes = {
  products: PropTypes.array,
  total: PropTypes.string,
  onCheckoutClicked: PropTypes.func
}

export default Cart
```

You can find similar example here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: seems nice, one question, in render we are using "const hasProducts = products.length > 0", how did we get products? it is not mentioned as parameters to the component.

Comment: may be putting it around interface will solve, but not sure. like  extends React.Component<ISomeInterface,any>

Comment: Good question. You use this.props.<propertyname> to get the passed property. I will update my answer now.